# Having problems parsing HTML + Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to parse my html file with jsoup and I need to build Elements object which will contain an array of divs (like on picture below). How can i do that with select syntax?

[image]

Each element of Elements must contains "news":

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe select `.view-content div`?

Comment: Sorry, but it does not work.

Comment: Then try with `.view-content>div`. If it doesn't work try with `.views-row`

Comment: If you want to get an element with a specific class, you have to select `.classname`, in your specific case `.news`

Comment: Ok and how to add specify table with id = newsMain. I don't need results from another two tables (usefulInfo and lastforum).

Comment: Id are specified with the `#` selector. You use it as `#id`, so `#newsMain`.

Comment: You're welcome! I'm making an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You select class names with the dot (`.`) selector, and ids with `#`, so:

```
Elements newsClass = myDocument.select(".news");
Elements newsMainId = myDocument.select("#newsMain");
```